# Different execution time for sql query for different parameter

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
select * from employeeTable where emp_dept = 'MAN-X'

select * from employeeTable where emp_Id = 'ada1-asda3-sdaa-kle1'
```

I am using oracle DB to execute this query.

Case 1:
When i execute the first query in which i give emp_dept as parameter it takes only 0.05s to execute with 100 rows returned

Case 2:
When i execute the second query in which i give emp_Id as parameter it takes more than 6s to execute with one or no rows returned

P.S: emp_dept and emp_Id are not primary keys

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: emp_dept probably has a unique key defined. Even if not, 6 sec for 100 rows is ridiculous for any database. Share the table description if possible. May help figure out the issue.

Comment: hi, i think you have misread it. It takes 0.05s to fetch 100 rows. Case 2 is causing the problem

Comment: How many rows in the table? are you using SqlPlus? have you tried SQL_TRACE?

Comment: You say the columns are not primary keys, but `EMP_DEPT` could still be indexed. Check the table definition.

Comment: We suspect that `emp_dept` is indexed but `emp_Id` isn't.  To determine what columns in `employeeTable` table are indexed, do this: `select index_name, table_name, uniqueness from dba_indexes where table_name = 'employeeTable';`

Comment: Thank you. It was not indexed. Thats why the loading time was too slow.